# How to delete a facebook feed post/comment in php?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I want to delete a facebook post or comment that is on my facebook feed. I tried to follow facebook docs,but no in vain. 
Here is my code for post delete request.

```
$postid = "2512732972186856_2511181632341990";

$token = facebook user access token

$feed = $this->facebook->deletes($postid,array (), $token);
```

When I run this query it says :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3,
    "fbtrace_id": "A9fyXxLUY3ui9S3CqiCuIDJ"
  }
}
```

However it is important to mention that i didn't create post in page, my post is in my facebook feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create or delete posts on your Profile, you can only create posts on a Page, and you can only delete posts made by your App.

The error message actually tells you that those actions are only available for Pages (with a Page Token).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
i want to delete facebook posts on user behalf ,how can i delete ?

Comment: Thanks for contacting me , then how can i delete posts or comments through php ? it is very important for me. Please suggestions if not possible deletion.

Comment: it does not matter which language, not possible means not possible